websocket not working with kubernetes replicas
I am implementing an application with chat feature using websocket on k8s including mongodb, nodejs and reactjs. I deployed 3 pods db, api, web and they work fine with ingress nginx but when I increased the api replicas to 2, it seems nginx only has connection to 1 of the 2 replicas and I can't use the chat feature.
Here is my nginx configuration:
upstream websocket {
    hash $remote_addr consistent;
    server api-service.my-namespace:3000;
}

error_page  404  =200 /;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    index        index.html;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api {
        return 302 http://api-service.my-namespace:3000/;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://websocket/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #aio threads;
    }
    location ~* \.io {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;
        #aio threads;

    }
}

